# How do I add a button that would copy displayed text in vue.js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm trying to add a button that would enable me to copy a snippet of code that is in view to the clipboard for a code catalog application in vue.js.

When I use the vue clipboard library and attempt this in the example component:

```
<div class="full-screen-code-snippet">
  {{ example.codeSnippet }}
</div>

<div class="full-screen-copy-button">
<button v-clipboard:copy="example.codeSnippet"></button>    
</div>
```

the snippet displays properly but the button does not. What's going on? How should I go about making this button?

Comment: Native browser API is also available: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Clipboard_API

Answer (score 0):

You should be using it like : `v-clipboard="variableName"` or with `:copy` the same .
you can read more about it [here](https://github.com/euvl/v-clipboard) or [this one](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-clipboard2)

```
<template id="t">
  <div class="container">
    <input type="text" v-model="message">
    <button type="button"
      v-clipboard:copy="message"
      v-clipboard:success="onCopy"
      v-clipboard:error="onError">Copy!</button>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  template: '#t',
  data: function () {
    return {
      message: 'Copy These Text'
    }
  },
  methods: {
    onCopy: function (e) {
      alert('You just copied: ' + e.text)
    },
    onError: function (e) {
      alert('Failed to copy texts')
    }
  }
})
</script>
```